# Portability between Unix shells - am I thinking about the issue correctly?

Tags: bash, shell, cross-platform, portability, sh

Whenever I write shell scripts (mostly software development utilities or build tools) I've generally tried to avoid using bash in favor of using plain old sh for portability. However lately I've been running into more and more issues where useful features are not available, or behavior is actually less consistent across systems using sh then it is using bash, since sh is aliased to different shells...

As I understand it, sh is the oldest Unix shell and carefully written sh scripts should in theory run on pretty much any system out there... but it also seems there are about 9000 different variants of every major shell, too. Doesn't using bash as your script interpreter effectively limit your script's portability? Sure, no problems on OS X or pretty much any Linux out there, but what about the BSDs? Solaris, AIX, HP-UX? What do you do if you really want to run on everything?

I know bash can be installed on virtually any OS but it is really a first class citizen on all relevant modern systems? Does it come pre-installed? I'm just not really sure whether it's best to avoid or embrace bash with the intent of having the most consistent and portable overall experience.

Comment: You might be giving yourself a false sense of portability... I've commonly found issues from commands you use from shells, not just the shell itself. Our ancient systems at work have bash but really old versions of sed, find, grep etc.

Comment: Also remember that on manu Linux systems, `/bin/sh` is just a symlink to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: And on Ubuntu (since 6.10) it's Dash.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: But bash will enter sh-compatibility mode when called as /bin/sh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do you do if you really want to run on everything?

You follow the [POSIX standard for `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) (and the tools you're calling) and hope that the target OS does so too. Any modern product called "UNIX" must follow this standard, and customarily (though not universally), the standard shell will be called `/bin/sh`. The BSDs and Linux distros tend to aim at POSIX compatibility as well.

Comment: Beware that /bin/sh isn't the POSIX shell on some standard compliant Unixes like at least Solaris 10 and older.

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't using bash as your script interpreter effectively limit your script's portability?

Yes, but it depends on your target audience as you noted. If it's a short script, it's worth testing under `dash` (Ubuntu and Debian's default shell) for POSIX compatibility.

Whenever I start thinking about portability issues in my shell script, I switch to another language. Perl is widely available and generally a good choice for scripts, but if your tools are to be consumed by Python, Ruby, $lang developers, use $lang to its full potential.

Comment: I have seen a number of projects use Python and Perl for build-related scripts. On one hand it's incredibly powerful because you have a full programming language at your disposal, AND far, far more consistent behavior, but on the other hand you add another dependency. Everything is a trade off, I suppose. I guess it's mostly a philosophical question for me but I want to make the best technical decision and I simply don't have a lot of background knowledge and history of shells and all the different variants' intricacies.

Comment: Are the scripts you write for non-dynamic language developers (C, Java, etc.)? Or are these scripts available to anyone and any platform?

Comment: Almost exclusively for C++ projects, some open source and some proprietary and all with the intent of running on as many platforms as possible.

Comment: Ah, well, just write your script in C++. Problem solved! (Kidding!)

Comment: I haven't been able to find usage data to support this, but anecdotally (not what you want!), Perl is always available. It's an easy install without a package manager, and as long as you don't require CPAN modules, I don't see developers having any problems. With Perl, you don't have to worry about bizarre shell interpretations, and you can largely treat it as a better-than-bash language for maximum compatibility between versions.

Comment: Good to note - is the situation similar for Python?

Comment: The problem with Perl is that there are so many really old versions of it around, some even older than 5.10!  So you have to use `print`, for example, rather than `say`.  I have seen some Solaris machines still with 5.005 - that's from 1998.  Then again Python, there are some great features in 2.7, and more in 3, but there are lots of installations still on 2.4.  Wih Bash, 4 has been out for several years but many installations are still on 2.  Can you imagine Windows people still using Windows 95?

Comment: @cdarke: Good point! I really hope developers won't be working on 14 year old OSs, but maybe they like Netscape 6 too much. With Perl and Python, you at least know your script will be interpreted in the right language, and not in some compatible interpreter, so you've only gained version concerns as a downside. At least in Perl, you can put `use 5.10;` (or whatever version) at the top of scripts to enforce a minimum version, so the script will bail before accidentally deleting your hard drive due to a missing feature. Python doesn't have that built-in, but a quick conditional would work.

Comment: @JakePetroules: Just another option, but what about `awk`? If you restrict yourself to new-awk (ca. [1988](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations)) and keep things simple, it seems like you'll be OK. Of course, there's a long [list of compatibility tables](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/awkcompat.html), so you will need to compare a list of functions you'd like to use to see if it's viable. At least you can do `system()` calls in all versions but mawk on Windows 95...

Answer (score 0):

bash itself is just a plain C program, does not need special authority to run, can be put in any location. You can easily build it from source. Basically, you can run bash if you need to and doesn't need the administrator of the system to install it.

As long as it is in your path, you can always code your script with the line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```