# Unix utilities portability / compatibility table

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

For example, to convert from integer UNIX timestamp to a readable date, one can use `date` utility. However, the syntax is different on different platforms:

- on Linux - `date --date='@123456789'`
- on BSD - `date -r 123456789`

I'm not sure about Mac OS X, AIX, HP-UX and all the other flavors.

So programs are very different across the system, i.e. even bear a different name and usage syntax. For example, it's `seq 1 10` on Linux, but it's `jot 10 1` on BSD.

I know that there is a POSIX standard for shell (i.e. `sh`), but as far as I know, there is no POSIX standards for all the other utilities (like, manpage of `date` in Linux says nothing about conformance to something like POSIX / SysV / BSD standards).

This question - [Portability between Unix shells - am I thinking about the issue correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095473/portability-between-unix-shells-am-i-thinking-about-the-issue-correctly) - tackles the issue, but only about the shell itself, not the all other utilities.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Is there some sort of compatibility / portability comparison table available, that lists relevant differences on various major implementations of popular UNIX CLI tools, like `date`, `sed`, `awk`, etc?
2. Is there some sort of compatibility layer available, i.e. a minimal subset of what I can use to make sure that my shell scripts are portable, or some sort of shims (like in HTML / JavaScript) that bring missing functionality to alternative systems?

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a standard for basic commands like [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html#tag_20_30). There is however no support for "time since epoch in seconds' with it.

`seq` and `jot` are not specified by POSIX but it would be trivial to implement them with a shell script.

The minimal subset or compatibility layer you are looking for is the POSIX standard. Have a look to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing I'd highly recommend [O'Reilly's](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100292.do)  [UNIX in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596100299) which does an excellent job of collating the options for various flavors of UNIX for each command.

[image: book cover]